# Prove the intergral form of Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I just want to prove that a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous, if and only if $\exists\, g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $\forall\, x, \, y $,
$$f(y)-f(x)\le \int_x^yg(t) ~dt.$$
Setting $M=||g||_\infty$, I can prove that the right side implies the left, but I do not know how to prove the direction from left to right.

Comment: Why would $g$ be bounded?